# Fade Out parent element of a link which was appended (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I've got an empty div and I'm appending some text with html and two links in it. One link is normal with an href="some url" and the other is an element with a class. In short: this is a "yes | no" block. Yes is a normal url and NO is an element which will fade out the entire div.

The problem is that my div isn't fading out.

HTML:

(with css: display: block for hidding it from start)

JS:

```
   // THE TEXT
    var lbText = 'Thanks for helping us! Here\'s a preview of the part of gelattina you\'re about to take.';
        lbText = lbText + '<br /><img src="img/g10/OldGelattina'+cpNum+'.jpg" />';
        lbText = lbText + '<br /> <a href="claim.php?id='+cpNum+'">YES</a> | <a href="#" class="no">NO</a>'

                // I USE THIS CODE TO APPEND THE TEXT AND FADE IN THE ENTIRE DIV
$('.not-claimed').bind('click',function(){
            $('#lightboxcont').empty().append(lbText).css({
                'width': '30%',
                'height': '30%',
                'background': '#ffffff',
                'zIndex': '9999'
            }).fadeIn().center();

            $('#lightboxOverlay').fadeIn();
});
```

The next code is what I'm using to hide de entire div

```
$('#lightboxcont a').bind('click',function(){
        $("#lightboxOverlay").fadeOut();
        $('#lightboxcont').fadeOut().empty();
        return false;
    });
```

As I said, the problem is that the last jquery code isn't working and I don't know why.

I hope you understand, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery's bind method only is attached to matching elements that are available at the time it was first called. But they include the 'live' method which attaches to all matching elements now and that are created in the future. So if your appending the html after you bind the event try using:

```
$('#lightboxcont a').live('click',function(){
    $("#lightboxOverlay").fadeOut();
    $('#lightboxcont').fadeOut().empty();
    return false;
});
```

Change bind to live. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to attach the event to the `<a>` tags before you add them to the DOM?  If you were to call that "next code" from inside the `.not-claimed` click event, after the append, it will probably work

Does your "click" function ever get executed?

Answer (score 0):

Change `bind` to `live`. Bind won't work for dynamically added elements.

```
$('#lightboxcont a').live('click',function(){
    $("#lightboxOverlay").fadeOut();
    $('#lightboxcont').fadeOut().empty();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!!! the thing was solved using live instead of bind... I'm really really thankful!

$('#lightboxcont a').live('click',function(){
    $("#lightboxOverlay").fadeOut();
    $('#lightboxcont').fadeOut().empty();
    return false;
});

Greetings!!